# Can someone know my geolocation by replying to Whatsapp message?

Tags: geolocation, whatsapp

Is there any way a malicious actor could know my geolocation by replying to a Whatsapp message I have sent? Will being connected with a user allow me to see their geolocation, or would I have to reply to a message sent by another user before they could see this?

Comment: What do you mean be geolocation? How accurate do you mean? If I send you a remote image, I can grab your IP and get a rough city level idea of where you are.

Comment: Thanks @Sirens, Can you elaborate more about IP extraction from message? Is there a more precise way to extract the exact location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot gain the geolocation from a message you have sent someone via what’s app directly.

You can gain this if the message then proceeds to get you to do something else, such as open an app/link which then sends the receiver the location information (varying degrees of accuracy such as IP or GPS depending on app capabilities).